# Having issues with element assignment using TYPE

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am attempting to utilize `TYPE` for a generic array and don't seem to be getting the syntax quite right. I can get the code to work using `int`, but when I convert to `TYPE` the statement assigning values stops working.

Here is my Array creation:

```
struct DynArr
{
    TYPE *data;     /* pointer to the data array */
    int size;       /* Number of elements in the array */
    int capacity;   /* capacity ofthe array */
};


void initDynArr(DynArr *v, int capacity)
{
    assert(capacity > 0);
    assert(v!= 0);
    v->data = (TYPE *) malloc(sizeof(TYPE) * capacity);
    assert(v->data != 0);
    v->size = 0;
    v->capacity = capacity;
}


DynArr* createDynArr(int cap)
{
    assert(cap > 0);
    DynArr *r = (DynArr *)malloc(sizeof( DynArr));
    assert(r != 0);
    initDynArr(r,cap);
    return r;
}
```

And here is my call to modify:

```
void addDynArr(DynArr *v, TYPE val)
{    
    /* Add Element */
    *v->data = val;
    v->size++;    
}
```

The code is compiling, but `val` is not being assigned to the `data` fields.

**Edit**: In my test case I am passing `TYPE` as a `double`.

Test Function calls:

```
addDynArr(dyn, 3);
addDynArr(dyn, 4);
```

When Running the following val is reporting as 0:

```
printf("Val: %d ", val)
    /* Add Element */
    v->data[v->size] = val;
    v->size++;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation of `addDynArr()` is wrong.  You are always assigning `val` to the first element of `data`, not to the next available element at the end of `data`.  It needs to look more like this instead:

```
void addDynArr(DynArr *v, TYPE val)
{
    if (v->size < v->capacity)
    {
        /* Add Element */
        v->data[v->size] = val;
        v->size++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Remy, I had tested t[v->size] in a previous iteration and was unable to get it working.

I also have code to check for the end of the array and expand as needed, I have just clipped it out above as it works great and does not seem to be relevant to the assignment issue.

Comment: Please tell us how you are determining that it's not working. Better still, post a [Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise it's difficult to tell whether there is a bug in your real code, a bug in your test code or both.

Comment: I ran a few more checks, it turns out the val variable is failing to pass correctly into the function printing val reports '0' in the function when passing a number.

Comment: As suspected it is a problem with your testing. Use %f for doubles. Not %d.

Comment: And that is why they call me "newb". Thanks for the help Alan.